# Android xml layout:toRightOf

Tags: android, xml

I have a problem in `android:layout_toRightOf` it gives me `Invalid layout param` 
is there's a way to add this parameter to the project?

that's the code

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/text2"
    android:background="@color/red"/>
```

Comment: Using RelativeLayout?

Comment: `LinearLayout` does not have that attribute. Use `RelativeLayout`. Chek the docs. If you had you would not have posted this question

Comment: If you want it to use `LinearLayout` then set the orientation to `Horizontal` and don't use `toRightOf`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need text1 and text2 to both be children of the same parent `RelativeLayout`.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/text2"
        android:background="@color/red"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: If you are using LinearLayout you can not use the toRightOf... that is a property ONLY for RelativeLayouts.

Linear Layouts as the name says lays the objects in horizontal or vertical order. The RelativeLayouts is the one that relates objects to its parent or another object.

Comment: No, it won't. You cannot use toRightOf in a linear layout. "Right of" or "left of" are relative - that's why it's called a relative layout. The position of text1 is relative to text2.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use this layout_toRightof property in LinearLayout.

You are using relative layout and as it's name says relative so you have to define position of your text1 in relation to another view may be text2 in your case. So define your text1 layout as

```
    android:layout_toRightof="@+id/text2"
```

and declare another text2 as

```
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/text2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```